# Monitoring employees web\email\computer usage?

Tags: network-monitoring

As my company is growing I have noticed some potential abuse by my employees with web\emails and computer usage for personal use in work time. I want to monitor all my employee’s activities on their work machines. What should I do?

Comment: Talk to a lawyer about the legality of such spying and the prerequisites regarding paragraphs in their contracts.

Comment: There may also be rules against this in your jurisdiction. @TheUser1024 is right: this is more of a legal rather than a technical problem.

Comment: What exactly do you want to monitor? Are you looking to keep a track of which websites they visit or read their emails. One is legal the other not so much.

Comment: As noted, get the legal opinion. In many jurisdictions an illegal act by an employee at work can have a HUGE impact on the employer.  An employee in Canada downloaded and stored child pornography and the police seized the computer and servers as evidence. Major business issue for employer.  Employee went to jail.

Comment: Possible duplicate [Employee Tracking: Is there a similar software to Elance WorkView or oDesk “Team Room”?](http://superuser.com/questions/304444/employee-tracking-is-there-a-similar-software-to-elance-workview-or-odesk-team)

Comment: "What should I do?" Hire more people to monitor those monitoring logs.

Comment: That would surely kill moral in your company. I'd suggest build trust and loyalty with set guidelines which you enforce.

Answer (score 1):

Create a White List for Internet pages and limit the size for attachments in emails.

Monitoring each employee's activity is cost and time consuming and will just make them suspicious (rightly) and creative.